# Why this query takes so much time on my local server but not in production?

Tags: mysql, sql, wamp

So this query takes 11 seconds to execute on my localserver, but in production is almost inmedialy.

I have no clue why

```
SELECT c.id, c.franquicia_id, f.name, CONCAT(c.name,' ',c.surname) 
       contacto, c.created, DATE_FORMAT(c.created,'%d-%m-%Y') fecha 
FROM franquicias f, contacts c where f.id = c.franquicia_id 
 and c.created = (
                   select max(c2.created) 
                   from contacts c2 
                   WHERE c2.franquicia_id = c.franquicia_id
                 ) 
 and f.contract_id=2 
ORDER BY created DESC 
limit 10
```

It takes 11 seconds from the code and also tried from phpmyadmin and also takes 11 seconds

EXPLAIN

```
+----+--------------------+-------+------+----------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+-----------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type | possible_keys                    | key                      | key_len | ref                         | rows | Extra                           |
+----+--------------------+-------+------+----------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+-----------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
| 1  | PRIMARY            | f     | ref  | PRIMARY,FK_franquicias_contracts | FK_franquicias_contracts | 5       | const                       | 94   | Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+--------------------+-------+------+----------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+-----------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
| 1  | PRIMARY            | c     | ref  | FK_contacts_franquicias          | FK_contacts_franquicias  | 4       | admin_panel.f.id            | 73   | Using where                     |
+----+--------------------+-------+------+----------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+-----------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
| 2  | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | c2    | ref  | FK_contacts_franquicias          | FK_contacts_franquicias  | 4       | admin_panel.c.franquicia_id | 73   | NULL                            |
+----+--------------------+-------+------+----------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+-----------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
```

The database contacts: has 175.000 rows
the database contracts : has 5 rows
the database franquicias: has 1618

Server : mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.37-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Server: 1GB RAM, AMD Quadcore

Local : mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.17, for Win64 (x86_64)

Local : 16GB RAM I73820

Comment: Probably because you don't have the same indexes on both systems

Comment: Just verified and local and remote server have the same indexes, also database was copied from remote and installed in local using mysqldump.

Comment: `analyze table` perhaps. refresh stats. Unlikely, but maybe.

Comment: Try doing `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE [...]` both locally and on the server. This way you can exclude MySQL's query cache.

Comment: Do you get the same execution plan on both systems?

Comment: I run EXPLAIN on remote server and get the same EXPLAIN, but on remote the response time is Time: 0.003s

Comment: I see temporary and filesort which implies disk access. Could it be you're using an ordinary HDD locally and an SSD or something better remotely? Also, configuration may differ, thnks like InnoDB pool size, etc.